# what is reason of this error? I am using Filter function to filter the odd numbers from the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, debugging

I am getting this error I am using filter function to filter the odd values from list

[image]

Code:

```
l1=[1,2,4,5,6,79,100,200,500]
finnal_list=list(filter(lambda x: (x%2!=0),l1))
print(finnal_list)

l1=[1,2,4,5,6,79,100,200,500]
finnal_list=list(filter(lambda x: (x%2!=0),l1))
print(finnal_list)
```

Comment: You've used `filter` as a variable earlier in your code. That replaced the built-in `filter()` function. Don't use built-in function names as variables.

Answer (score 0):

Error clearly says in your previouse cells you've assigned filter varaible. It's a bad practice to use builtin names as vafraible names. Like so example
'

```
#old cells code 
filter = "some string"
#old cells code 


l1=[1,2,4,5,6,79,100,200,500]

finnal_list=list(filter(lambda x: (x%2!=0),l1))
print(finnal_list)
```

Throws error #

```
Error: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

### Fix

Simply clear that variable if you dont need it

```
#old cells code
filter = "some string"
#old cells code

l1=[1,2,4,5,6,79,100,200,500]  
del filter
finnal_list=list(filter(lambda x: (x%2!=0),l1))
print(finnal_list)
```

output #

```
[1, 5, 79]
```

Comment: You could improve your demo by matching their error. They didn't assign a string, they assigned a `filter` object.

Comment: @KellyBundy sure ...I'm away from desk...I will update it

Comment: (And I find it more likely that they assigned to `list`. i.e., I find `filter = filter(...)` rather unlikely and suspect they did `list = filter(...)`.)

Answer (score -1):

As others said you may have filter declared as variable. I think this is what you want

```
 li = [1,2,4,5,6,79,100,200,500]
 print(list(filter(lambda x: x if x%2!=0 else None,l1)))
```

Just to note **map,filter and reduce** etc are functional elements of python where

1. map normally used for transformation on an iterable
2. filter used to filter on an iterable

both map and filter takes iterable and returns returns iterable ,

3. reduce takes iterable produces single value that is further fed to reduce function.

These are handy functions that allows you to iterate over iterable without a loop.

Comment: -ve voter , share your opinion pls ?